# Is it possible to implement Unity's Shader Graph on a project that is not currently using the Lightweight template? How so?

Tags: templates, unity-game-engine, shader

I recently, as of a break after an rc1, migrated my work environment to Unity 2018.1. I'm loving the possibilities for Shader Graph, however, it's currently limited to running on the Lightweight template.

That makes sense (it is new), but my project which could benefit from it most is not using the Lightweight template. That template didn't even exist yet. Is it still possible for me to get shader graph functionality going in that project? Can I select or import a template after I've started a project? If so, how is this done?

I'm certain that this is a noob question, so thank you for your time!